# Getting the same set of random numbers on every run (using both int and real uniform distribution)

Tags: c++, c++11, random

On every run the same set of numbers are generated. I am not sure Why it is happening. is there any other way to generate the random numbers using random library that prevents this bug ? or is there anything wrong with my compiler or program ?

Is it necessary to declare std::default_random_engine as static ? because when it is not declared as static you'll get the same number on every iteration.
what is the cause behind that ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

float get_random() {
    static std::default_random_engine random;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution{0, 1};

    return distribution(random);
}

int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout<<get_random()<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt look like you're [seeding](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/seed/) the engine.

Comment: Got it. just realized that .(read on the reference page), thanks though.

Comment: What about the static and non static declaration ? Whats the matter behind that ?

Comment: When you make `random` static, it's created the first time `get_random` is called, and reused afterwards. So you get subsequent numbers from one random sequence. If you don't declare it static, then a new instance is created every time `get_random` is called, and you get the first number of a fresh random sequence. And since you aren't seeding the engine, you get the first number of the same sequence every time.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is the comments section bro

Answer (score 0):

`std::default_random_engine` is a PseudoRandom Number Generator, and PRNGs are just algorithms whose output resemble random numbers, but is not really random. They execute some determined operation on some internal state and output the next number based on that state, giving a predictable sequency. If you want a different sequence on every run using a PRNG, you need to "seed" it differently (i.e. initialize the internal state with a different value).

Alternatively, you can use instead a real random number generator, which in C++ is given by `std::random_device`, if implemented. If `std::random_device::entropy() > 0`, you can use it instead of `std::default_random_engine` to get non-deterministic results.

It can also be used to seed the PRNG, if non-deterministic:

```
#include <chrono>

uint32_t generate_seed() {
    // The most portable way to generate non-deterministic number
    // is via std::random_device, provided entropy is > 0.
    {
        std::random_device rd;
        if(rd.entropy() > 0.0) {
            return rd();
        }
    }

    // Random device is deterministic, you need some other
    // platform specific entropy source.
    // Good alternatives are:
    //  - /dev/urandom, on Linux;
    //  - BCryptGenRandom() function, on Windows;
    //  - RDRAND or RDSEED instruction, on
    //    recent enough Intel processors.
    // Bad alternatives are:
    //  - time() function, which is predictable if
    //    you know when the program was executed,
    //    and is repeatead if you run the program
    //    more than once per second.
    //  - std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(), which
    //    is a little better than time() because it
    //    changes faster, thus is less likely to be repeated.
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
        .time_since_epoch().count();
}

float get_random() {
    static std::default_random_engine random{generate_seed()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution{0, 1};

    return distribution(random);
}
```

Comment: The problem hasn't been solved yet. The same thing happens with your function too: on every run same numbers every time. I was told that I needed to seed the `std::default_random_engine` or `std::mt19937` to get different set of numbers every time. **but how can I seed those when I am providing std::random_device on initialization ?**

Comment: That means the `std::random_device` of your compiler is deterministic. In that case, you either should change compiler or use a different source of entropy. On Linux, you can read an `uint32_t` value from the file `/dev/urandom` and use that as your seed.

Comment: I've updated the answer to test whether `std::random_device` is deterministic or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take six pieces of paper, and write the numbers 1 - 6 on them. Put them in a bag and mix them all up. Now pour them out of the bag and spread them out randomly on your desk.

What does the first one say? Maybe 3! A nice, random result! Excellent.

What does the second one say? Maybe 5! Awesome, also seems pretty random.

What does the third one say? Maybe 2! Sweet.

---

Now if you only wanted three random numbers then you're done.

What do you the next time you want three random numbers?

Do you:

1. Look at the first three pieces of paper on your desk again, or
2. Put the pieces of paper back in the bag and re-shuffle it?

The second one, of course! Otherwise you'll just get the same results.

---

PRNGs are *deterministic*. They're not really random. They just feed you a sort-of-predetermined sequence, in order. The sequence itself looks like randomness but, for a given seed, the actual sequence choice is already made by the system when you constructed the generator.

So, when you construct another generator, with the same seed (or no seed, so a default is used), *you will get the same three pieces of paper again*.

The way to use a PRNG is to construct *one* generator then keep asking it for the next "random" number in the sequence. That's why you make that object `static`: so that it is instantiated once and re-used on subsequent invocations of the function.